# Creating a new URL with Java on my webApp returns 404. How to set it up properly?

Tags: java

I have a webApp named "testApp". I have created an URL for the sole purpose of just pinging this address. For some reason my code returns 404. How to set it up properly?

My code:

```
    public class PingEndpoint {
  
  public static String URL = "http://localhost:8080/testApp/ping";

  public static void urlEndpoint() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    URL url = new URL(URL);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
    connection.connect();
    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println(URL + "PingEndpoint server responseCode: " + responseCode);
    if (responseCode == 200) {
      LogManager.getLogger().info("Server status: " + responseCode);
    } else {
      LogManager.getLogger().info("Error, Server status: " + responseCode);
    }
  }
}
```

My endpoint creation:

PingResource class

```
@Path("ping")
@RequestScoped
public class PingResource {
  private static final Ping PING = new Ping("transactions");
  @GET
  @Produces({APPLICATION_XML, APPLICATION_JSON})
  public Ping ping() {
    return PING;
  }
}
```

Ping Class

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Ping {

  @XmlAttribute
  public final String result = "ok";
  @XmlAttribute
  public final String from;

  public Ping() {
    from = "ping";
  }

  public Ping(String from) {
    this.from = from;
  }
}
```

ApplicationResources Class

```
@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath("testApp")
public class ApplicationConfig extends Application {

  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> resources = new java.util.HashSet<>();

    addRestResourceClasses(resources);
    return resources;
  }

  private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
    resources.add(fi.western.wroute.foli.nettilataus.pingService.PingResource.class);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hard to tell as there is no server code here, but a quick guess. You have a typo in your url. You said the name of your application was `testApp` and your url says `tesApp`.

Comment: Typo was only on the post here. Unfortunately.

Comment: So then it is still hard to tell. Your server apparently responds as you get a 404 status back, but it can't find the resource you are trying to find. So without any code or configuration of what you have done on the server side (including your testApp) we are really just guessing.

Comment: Post some code in your question if we are to help you further. Anyway, I would start by double checking if you can even reach the url from a browser. If that also fails, you have a problem on the server side and should check your url mappings.

Comment: Your client tries to perform a `HEAD` request but you only implement `@GET`. Normally, a HTTP 405 would be returned but even that would be depended on the actual JAX-RS implementation.